# Can one distinguish QED (or QCD) from QED (or QCD) plus higher field powers?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, quantum-chromodynamics

The Lagrangian of QED is based on minimal coupling; it contains a term proportional to $F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$ for the electromagnetic field.

The QED Lagrangian is the simplest Lagrangian with U(1) gauge symmetry. However, one could imagine more complex Lagrangians with the same symmetry. One example is a Lagrangian with an additional term proportional to $(F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu})^2$.

In QCD, one can ask the same question, with the gluon field term $G_{a\mu\nu}G^{a\mu\nu}$ and SU(3).

Is there a reason, preferably theoretical, why such higher powers do not arise in the Lagrangian, even though they have the correct gauge symmetry? Is there literature about this?

Comment: They do arise in [effective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler–Heisenberg_Lagrangian) actions.

Comment: $F_{\mu\nu} = \partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu$, so you can see the dimension of $F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$ is 4, while the dimension of its square would be 8, so the coupling in front of it must compensate for that ( the Lagrangian densinty has to contain terms of mass 4 dimension, since the action is dimensionless - $S = \int d^4x \mathcal{L}$ ). A summary for the meaning of this can be found in the answer given here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/281462/whats-the-significance-of-a-dimensionless-coupling-constant.

Comment: Ok, so the renormalization would be affected. I guess this means tha the coupling at small differences i s different. Is that correct?

Comment: Is there also another physical difference - such as different Feynman diagrams?